# LocationManager requestLocationUpdates minTime parameter not working

Tags: mobile, time, gps, locationmanager, min

I´m working with GPS in my applicaction. It works correctly in one of my mobile phone, but when I installed the software in other mobile the "minTime" parameter of LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates not working.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minTime, misDistance,locationListener);
```

I have such as "minTime=120000" (2minutes) and "minDistance=30" (30 meters).

This fail may be due to the accuracy of the second mobile (is worse)?

Answer (score 0):

The minTime parameter is just a hint, see here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4245527/1127492