# GPS location updates constantly in Android 2.2 and Android 2.3

Tags: android, gps, location

I have developed an app that using current location every 30 seconds later. The app is finished. It runs perfectly on ICS (Android 4), JellyBean(Android 4.1) devices, but when I run the app on Android 2.3 or Android 2.2, app GPS updates at every 2/3 seconds later and constantly updating. Though my code is done for 30 seconds and it works perfectly (30 seconds later) in Android 4,4.1 but does not work Android 2.3 or 2.2.

I am sharing the code....

```
 public class GPSManager
{
    //private static final int gpsMinTime = 60000;
    //private static final int gpsMinDistance = 0;

    private long gpsMinTime = 0;
    private float gpsMinDistance = 0;

    private static LocationManager locationManager = null;
    private static LocationListener locationListener = null;
    private static GPSCallback gpsCallback = null;

    public GPSManager(long gpsMinTime,float gpsMinDistance)
    {   
        this.gpsMinTime = gpsMinTime;
        this.gpsMinDistance = gpsMinDistance;

        GPSManager.locationListener = new LocationListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(final Location location)
            {
                if (GPSManager.gpsCallback != null)
                {
                    GPSManager.gpsCallback.onGPSUpdate(location);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(final String provider)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(final String provider)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(final String provider, final int status, final Bundle extras)
            {

            }
        };
    }

    public GPSCallback getGPSCallback()
    {
        return GPSManager.gpsCallback;
    }

    public void setGPSCallback(final GPSCallback gpsCallback)
    {
        GPSManager.gpsCallback = gpsCallback;
    }

    public void startListening(final Context context)
    {
        if (GPSManager.locationManager == null)
        {
            GPSManager.locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }

        final Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_MEDIUM);  // accuracy_midium
        criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(true);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_MEDIUM);

        final String bestProvider = GPSManager.locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        if (bestProvider != null && bestProvider.length() > 0)
        {
            GPSManager.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, this.gpsMinTime,
                    this.gpsMinDistance, GPSManager.locationListener);

        }
        else
        {
            final List<String> providers = GPSManager.locationManager.getProviders(true);

            for (final String provider : providers)
            {
                GPSManager.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, this.gpsMinTime,
                        this.gpsMinDistance, GPSManager.locationListener);
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopListening()
    {
        try
        {
            if (GPSManager.locationManager != null && GPSManager.locationListener != null)
            {
                GPSManager.locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSManager.locationListener);
            }

            GPSManager.locationManager = null;
        }
        catch (final Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }


}
```

And my Location update code is here:

```
private static final long GPS_MINTIME = 30000;
private static final float GPS_MINDISTANCE = 100;
gpsManager = new GPSManager(GPS_MINTIME,GPS_MINDISTANCE);
                gpsManager.startListening(getApplicationContext());
                gpsManager.setGPSCallback(this);
```

Any Idea why this happening. Thanks.

Comment: I found much the same on my phone. When it was on 2.3 the minUpdateTime seemed to be ignored, once the OS was upgraded to ICS it honoured the contract.

Comment: Are you sure that you are setting min time to `30Secs`, I see that you have setted to `0` in your current code

Comment: It is strange! My app running OS 2.3/2.2 blinks/flicker every 2/3 seconds later to update GPS current location. Surprised!

Comment: @VenomVendor: I pass value in constructor of this class. That is 30 seconds. Already working fine in Android 4 - 4.1 versions. Any idea?

Comment: Try changing the distance from `0` to `10`

Comment: @VenomVendor: please see my actual code that I am using. So any idea now?

Answer (score 0):

Change `GPS_MINTIME` greater than `6000` 
 It will work perfectly.

Comment: My GPS_MINTIME is 30 seconds (30000 ms), have you tested @VenomVendor.

Comment: @NickT The code has been [Updated](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15143675/revisions)

Answer (score 0):

please check this answer on SO
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4245527/1438915

in api < 4.0 min time is not compulsorily taken into 
consideration it may be inaccurate sometimes. **works like hint**.

**UPDATE**

from docs [INFO](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) i think you should read this.

Comment: app is using 30000ms (30 seconds) and Min distance is 100 , so any idea now?

Comment: @user748178 sorry its my mistake.

Comment: thank you for your response. If you find any solution please share here.

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment, it is a known (but not widely reported bug/feature). See [Google Groups Post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!search/%22sean%2420barbeau%22/android-platform/NElQDFGppZk/so-drODfyjIJ)
I did add my support to this proposal, but the thread is now closed as it's fixed in 4.1

Comment: That means, I have to upload the app with this bug? Any suggestion?

Comment: I ended up putting the location listener in a bound service with its own scheduler. I passed MY min update time in as a parameter to the the service which ran a little state machine governed by a  timer.

Comment: I was also planing to control gps update in my own scheduler/timer. Thank you @NickT

Comment: I'm afraid that it's the only way to do it if you want to support Gingerbread and not hammer the battery.