# GPS Lat, Long change for same current location again and again

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to  find the speed of Device. I am getting every good using speed formula. BUT I HAVE ONE PROBLEM. i am getting different lat,long if i put the Mobile at same place, then after few second its location change and also speed,and distance etc.
I want that if device is not in running then it only show one current lat, long(speed=0) not different, because location is not changing.
I am using this class:

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener 
{
 boolean first_time=true;
private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

double prev_lat=0.0;
double prev_long=0.0;
// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES =  0;// meters  (make the time and distance to 0,0 so that we could get the updates very quickly
// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 0;//1000 * 60 * 1; //  minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

int hour1=0;
int minute1=0;
int second1=0;
int hour2=0;
int minute2=0;
int second2=0;

int time_dif=0;

private static float distance=0;
static double speed=0;

public GPSTracker(Context context) 
{
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation()
{
    try 
    {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Either Network or GPS is not available in your Mob " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // no network provider is enabled
        } 
        else 
        {
            this.canGetLocation = true;

            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            /*if (isNetworkEnabled)              
            {
                  //Update the location of a user after t time and d distance... where we have declared time and distance as 0,0 which means to get frequent updates.
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                if (locationManager != null) 
                {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location "+location.getLatitude() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
                    }
                } 
            }
            //*/
            //else if (isGPSEnabled)
             if (isGPSEnabled)
            {   //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "inside 'isGpdenabled' " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (location == null) 
                {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //*/
        }

    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS()
{
    if(locationManager != null)
    {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }       
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}


/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() 
{
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enable. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

//((((( Find distance between two geolocation  )))
public float FindDistance(float lat1, float lng1, float lat2, float lng2)
    {
         double earthRadius = 6371000; //meters
            double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
            double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
            double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                       Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
                       Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
            double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
            float dist = (float) (earthRadius * c);

            return dist;

    }


public double Set_Speed_inKM()
{
    speed=speed*3.6;   // Formula to Convert M/Sec --> KM/Sec

    return speed;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
  if(!first_time )
  {

  if( prev_lat!=location.getLatitude() & prev_long!=location.getLongitude())
    {
    //showtoast("Location Changed");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    second1=c.get(Calendar.SECOND);     

    if(second2>second1)
        second1=60+second1;

      time_dif=second1-second2;       
      time_dif=Math.abs(time_dif);


    second2=second1;

     distance=FindDistance((float)prev_lat,(float)prev_long,(float)location.getLatitude(),(float)location.getLongitude());

     if(time_dif!=0)
      speed=distance/time_dif;

     Set_Speed_inKM();

        Log.e("LOCATION CHANGED", "data"+location.getLatitude()+"\n");

            //Calling Function and Passing Value
          sendMessageToActivity(location ,time_dif,"NewLocation", this.mContext);

            //prev_lat=location.getLatitude();
          //  prev_long=location.getLongitude();

        }
     }
         prev_lat=location.getLatitude();
        prev_long=location.getLongitude();

        first_time=false;
    }


//((( This Function SEND data 2 ACTIVITY )))))))
private static void sendMessageToActivity(Location l,float time_diff, String msg, Context c) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent("GPSLocationUpdates");
    // You can also include some extra data.
    intent.putExtra("Status", msg);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putParcelable("Location", l);
    intent.putExtra("Location", b);
    intent.putExtra("speed", ""+speed);
    intent.putExtra("time_diff", ""+distance);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(c).sendBroadcast(intent);
}


@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

//Show-Toast Message
public void showtoast(String str)
{
//  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Comment: I see only one problem ... you used **very bad code from androidhive** ... service doesn't need context because is a context itself ... also you cannot call new operator on service derived class from your code ... but about your so called problem: MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES =  0 + the fact that GPS is not accurate it causing "location change" ... you shouldn't bother about this as prolly the change is very small (smaller then accuracy of GPS) ...

Comment: @Selvin thank you, but please tell me where to change the code, please i am really stuck in it

Comment: everthing ... but even whitout this bad code ... it will works in the same way ... change MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES to something like at least 5 then you shouldn't get changes...

Comment: @Selvin Why the whole code is not good for getting gps lat, long?

Comment: because it was taken from androidhive ... the source of bad code ... for FSM sake I had already write why this code is bad (here in at least 10 othe question using this (again) very bad code)

Comment: @Selvin I also have change the MIN_DISTANCE.. to 5, and what about the MIN_TIME, what should be its values, 0 is ok or change it???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104260/discussion-between-pir-fahim-shah-and-selvin).

Comment: use the google MIN_TIME is only hint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245193/android-locationmanager-requestlocationupdates-with-mintime-0-not-working-as-ex/4245527#4245527 ... i have no time for chat

Answer (score 1):

The accuracy of the GPS is not absolute, so even a static device will show different locations in successive readings. You can add a method that detects if the mobile is static or not, by reading the accelerometer - if the delta between two readings if bigger than some threshold - the device is moving. If it's too small - it's not moving. To determine the delta - put the device on a table and see what values you get.