# How to draw a polyline with more than 100k LatLng on Google Maps in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, polygon

my problem is as follows: I am drawing a live polyline in Google Maps which works fine so far.
Now I save all the fetched LatLng points and later I want to load the path which I travelled on again.
As soon as I have more than 100k it takes a few seconds to draw that polyline, and if I have to draw more than 1 Million LatLng as a polyline it takes very very long to draw it.

Now I would like to know whether it is possible to draw a polyline with more than 100k LatLng or even more in reasonable time (reasonable time means 1-2 seconds at all!)?
Or do I have to change to some TileServer - is there an "already" built in version?

Thank you very much for your help in advance

Comment: 100k polylines at one time seems so ridiculous. I think drawing itself would take more than a second. Maybe you can try sampling and pagination to your data.

Comment: Sampling data is what I am already doing. If I pass the same point it will not be added to my ArrayList. Since I am doing Ultramarathons on 1.3km tracks it might happen that I pass the same point over and over again but in the end I gather more than 100k points if I have to run for 12 hours and even longer. Other programs they have no problems with drawing a polyline with that many points. The only problem is that I cannot see their source code since it is not Open Source.

Comment: After 12 hours you will have run more then 130 km? So 100 rounds on an 1.3 km track. You wanna display 100 lines on the track? Why?

Comment: If you would run 130 km from east to west . Then how would you display 100 K points on a screen with resolution of 2000 points?

Comment: If you looked in their source code, or in mines, you would see that they would only draw every fifth point or less.

Comment: If I ran 130km on a 1.3km track, I get a lot of LatLng. They are added to my ArrayList and then I draw one Polyline with all the points.  Let us assume I use requestLocationUpdates(1 sec, 1 meter) the ArrayList is filling up quite fast. I know I can play around with the requestLocationUpdates and with displaying just every 5th point and so on but I thought it might be possible to display all the points in reasonable time. If not I am satisfied with sampling my data. Would you mind providing me your part of the source code where you handle it (every 5th point)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest one of the following two solutions:

1. You reduce the number of points saved. I also record every running race, hike, bike ride, etc., but even after 8 hours I only have about 10,000 points in my GPX file. My recording software only saves the coordinates about every 4 seconds or 40 meters (which is more than enough for marathons).
2. Or you can simplify the polyline. There is the command `PolyUtil.simplify(fullLine, tolerance)`, which deletes intermediate points if they are all more or less on a straight line. I have been able to reduce the amount of data to 5-10% in this way without the track becoming much less accurate, as the following example shows.

   **Original track:**
   [image: Full Track]

   **Simplified track (tolerance 20m, 8% data):**
   [image: Simplified Track (Tolerance 20m, 8% data)]

Comment: Ah great, thank you very much: I did not know that method: PolyUtil.simplify(fullLine, tolerance). I will take a look into that! Reducing the number of points is what I am already doing. I just thought there might be something which can handle it and Google Maps is not intended for this amount of data.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried it with the PolyUtil.simplify method and it reduced my 350k points to 9 points with 40 meter tolerance.
Now I am thinking about how to accelerate the saving/loading/dsiplaying.
As of now I am saving all the points to my sqlite database and when I want to display the route, I am loading all the points and applying the PolyUtil.. method on it.
Although I use an index for my columns, etc. it still takes a few seconds to display the reduced path. Hopefully, I can figure it out how to make it faster: reading/writing/displaying.

Comment: There is an app called Geo Tracker and although I changed the settings to: 1 meter, 1 second, I am able to display the whole path instantly. Sadly, it is closed source. Thats why I cannot see what he is actually doing. I exported a run that lasted for 12 hours with 250k points and it was displayed immediatly.

Comment: @Bernd: Am I reading correctly? You were able to reduce the 350k points to 9 (with tolerance 40m)? Or did you mean 9k? Only 9 points is not possible, unless you run endlessly on a circle of only 20m radius ;-).
Do you do additional calculations such as adding up distance, calculating speed, etc. while saving/loading? Write to the log file at the beginning of saving/loading/displaying, then you can immediately see what takes so much time.

Comment: @ Bernd: If you run for 12 hours and save your coordinates every second, that only gives you 60x60x12=43'200 points, far away from 350'000. How do you get such large numbers?

Comment: no, it was really reduced to 9 points by using 40m tolerance

I am pretty sure I did something wrong with the requestLocationUpdates (I think I understood it wrong?!).
Just for being overly exactly, I used it that way yesterday

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(GPS_PROVIDER, minTimeMs * 1000, (float) minDistanceMeter, this);

Here I used minTimeMs: 1, minDistanceMeter: 1 and so I got 350k points in just 30 minutes.

The other ~350k points I received was with this Geo Tracker app where I ran for 12h although I used 1 sec, 1 meter.

Thats why I am so flabbergast.

Comment: no, I was not walking in a circel with a 20m radius but it would have been funny :)

Comment: Here is my app on Github: [link](https://github.com/bernd-roth/Ultrarunning)

The part where I draw the polyline is here

//Background work here
List<Run> allEntries = db.getSingleEntryOrderedByDateTime(numberOfRun);
...

Comment: yes, when I save all the data that I receive to my database, I am saving lat lng, time, laps, heart rate, altitude, ...

and there is an index on the column: number_of_run

and when I am displaying it, I select the number of my run and put all the values in a list.
Ah, thanks for pointing me to one problem: Although I am just interested at the moment in lat lng I am selecting all fields.
This is something I have to adapt.

Comment: @ Bernd: Can you list the lat/lon/ele/time data of about 20 **consecutive** points in a way like 
47.060884 9.490454 539.758700 2022-12-15T09:50:11.717Z
47.060793 9.490428 539.698545 2022-12-15T09:50:19.637Z
...

Comment: I went for a walk to try the settings with dist:0, time: 1 and I got so many latlng again

13-11-2023 14:12:17,48.1821,16.3607
13-11-2023 14:12:18,48.1821,16.3607
13-11-2023 14:12:18,48.1821,16.3607
13-11-2023 14:12:19,48.1821,16.3607
13-11-2023 14:12:19,48.1821,16.3607
13-11-2023 14:12:19,48.1821,16.3607
13-11-2023 14:12:20,48.1821,16.3607
13-11-2023 14:12:20,48.1821,16.3607
13-11-2023 14:12:20,48.1821,16.3607
13-11-2023 14:12:20,48.1821,16.3607
13-11-2023 14:12:21,48.1821,16.3608
13-11-2023 14:12:21,48.1821,16.3608
13-11-2023 14:12:21,48.1821,16.3608

Comment: So, I am handling the requestLocationUpdates wrong, pretty obvious

Comment: Yes, you have to fix this first, then we can see further. Hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245193/android-locationmanager-requestlocationupdates-with-mintime-0-not-working-as-ex

Comment: So, I changed it to 1 sec, 40 meters and now I was walking for another ~30 minutes and I received 1128 points. Moreover, using the PolyUtil.simplify statement the line is almost straight although I made some hooks. I have to see how that looks like as soon as I ran another 12/24 hours Ultramarathon. Maybe I will reduce the meters to 20m or even less, I have to play around with that settings.

Comment: @ Bernd: Did you read the link in my last post? And PolyUtil.simplify works perfect for me, see my pictures. The second one is simply the result of the command PolyUtil.simplify(polyline, 20).

Comment: yeah I read it - Thats why I deactivated the PolyUtil now in order to see how it looks like without it.

Comment: Now I am just trying to find out the "best" solution for me. Using the PolyUtil or reducing the requestLocationUpdates to 10 meters, something like that

Comment: That is not the point: requestLocationUpdates does not do what we expect. In order to get results that match your expectations, you should delete programmatically the surplus measuring points as suggested in the link. Otherwise you cannot know whether 30 minutes will deliver 1000 or 10000 measuring points. You will then see whether PolyUtil.simplify is necessary or not.

Comment: I upvoted it. I think we solved it with your suggestions like the PolyUtil, adapting the requestLocationUpdates, etc. If I get every second a LatLng coordinate for 24 hours it will be 86400 points and they can be further reduced. I think there will not be so many problems with drawing the result then.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and happy programming to you too :)